# android kotlin click listener loses its "click methods" after some time

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi I'm implementing click listeners in the following way but after some time the methods and variables inside the listener's closure get the wrong values or something. Let me explain the implementation of the listener a little better a for loop creates the listener for a set of image views then later in the program the for loop is called a second time and it resets the listener methods and variables to different values. Everything works great for about 30 minutes but then for some reason, the listener's methods and variables start having the wrong values. Has anybody ever heard of this behavior or can tell me where I've gone wrong with the code? Keep in mind that the listener I'm about to paste here is just a small piece of a 1014 line class. I'm hoping somebody can spot How I'm implementing the listener wrongly and can give me some advice on how to "reset" the listener so that it's variables and values stay over time. Hopefully you can read the code without putting it in an editor but feel free to copy it for readability's sake Here is the code for the image view listener with comments.

```
//image views are held in an array
//set an image view in its imageview container
imgArr0[slotId1].invalidate()
imgArr0[slotId1].setImageDrawable(null)
//drw is not defined in this example
imgArr0[slotId1].setImageDrawable(drw)

/*if video or image id is set to image then set a listener for the image
*/

/*slotId1 is not defined in this example but it is simply a counter to iterate over the ImageView array
*/

if (videoOrImageId0[slotId1] == "image") {


     //null any listeners that might be attached to the image view
                           imgArr0[slotId1].setOnClickListener(null)

//set or reset the listener 
imgArr0[slotId1].setOnClickListener() {

`enter code here`//if the current config is portrait then set a new image image

if (currentConfig0 == "portrait0") {
act0.lrgImage0.invalidate()
                                    act0.lrgImage0.setImageDrawable(null)

/*drw is not defined in this example but works fine in the production script                                        
*/
act0.lrgImage0.setImageDrawable(drw)

} 
--calmchess
```

ccc tv application with problem.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjdbN.jpg)[image]![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaMnc.

Comment: Why are you not using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to set the images in the ImageViews? I believe the activity loses its data because of battery optimizations of the system or because of getting killed, nonetheless it's better to use Glide with `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)` so the image would be cached in storage and Glide will handle that, same can be found in Picasso.

Comment: Picasso does look interesting.  It's pretty tough to use something when I didn't know it existed in the first place. : )  Thanks for sharing I'll look into it. I am interested in further optimization of my app and I think Picasso can do just that.

Comment: added an image to the post so people can see better about how my app works, it dynamically populates a scroller with clickable images that either play a video or shows an image. As I've said the id for the video/image is being lost especially on videos after some time. Picasso will work for this app? New images are populated on every search of a key term. Currently, the loading of the images is quick about 500 ms./image I don't know how I would cache the images since those are dynamically being loaded from a web server and the possibilities of which images are loaded next is huge.

Comment: What you should do is save the instance state so the UI state will back to normal without lost IDs if in case any ID/s get/s lost because of system freeing up the memory. As I believe you're not doing memory management so far but remember, you have to do that because with that many images/videos, memory management is the key to maintain the UI state. The two articles in the next comment are very good to save the instance state. Also, Read about Disk Caching and Resource management [here](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html).

Comment: [Android ViewModels: State persistence — SavedState](https://proandroiddev.com/viewmodels-state-persistence-savedstate-54d015acad82) and [Saving UI state with ViewModel SavedState and Dagger](https://proandroiddev.com/saving-ui-state-with-viewmodel-savedstate-and-dagger-f77bcaeb8b08).

Comment: Sounds very reasonable and I will do. You are right I'm not doing much memory management at all it don't leak. But uses about 271 mb ram and I think I could do better with what you suggest. Thank you I'll report back maybe even with a before and after screen shot of the Android studio profiler.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to partially solve this question by destroying all the image views and their associated click listeners then rebuilding those... However I don't consider this issue completely solved so if anybody can provide a better solution I'd love to hear it because rebuilding the images every few minutes has to be using a lot of unnecessary hardware resources.

--calmchess